# Python comparing values from two dictionaries where keys match and one set of values is greater

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following datasets:

```
kpi = {
    "latency": 3,
    "cpu_utilisation": 0.98,
    "memory_utilisation": 0.95,
    "MIR": 200,
}

ns_metrics = {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-04T15:24:10.765000",
    "ns_id": "cache",
    "ns_data": {
        "cpu_utilisation": 0.012666666666700622,
        "memory_utilisation": 8.68265852766783,
    },
}
```

What I'm looking for is an elegant way to compare the cpu_utilisation and memory_utilisation values from each dictionary and if the two utilisation figures from ns_metrics is greater than kpi, for now, print a message as to which utilisation value was greater,i.e. was it either cpu or memory or both.  Naturally, I can do something simple like this:

```
if ns_metrics["ns_data"]["cpu_utilisation"] > kpi["cpu_utilisation"]:
    print("true: over cpu threshold")

if ns_metrics["ns_data"]["memory_utilisation"] > kpi["memory_utilisation"]:
    print("true: over memory threshold")
```

But this seems a bit longer winded to have many if conditions, and I was hoping there is a more elegant way of doing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use a loop to do this:

```
check_list = ["cpu_utilisation", "memory_utilisation"]
for i in check_list:
    if ns_metrics["ns_data"][i] > kpi[i]:
        print("true: over {} threshold".format(i.split('_')[0]))
```

if the key is different,you can use a mapping dict to do it,like this:

```
check_mapping = {"cpu_utilisation": "cpu_utilisation_1"}
for kpi_key, ns_key in check_mapping.items():
    ....
```